# What is "Syntax Error, unexpected tCONSTANT" error in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

I am currently on Lesson 9 in "Learn Ruby the hard way".

I have typed the the line number 6 exactly as the way its being instructed but still I am getting error while executing.

It says:

```
Syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting $end
```

```
puts " Here ^ are the days : ", days
```

Comment: This can happen in IRB (interactive ruby) even if I've hit Ctrl-C several times. I find I just exit IRB if I hit this in IRB.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have forgotten to close a string on a previous line. Here's the problem reproduced:

```
paul@paulbookpro ~ ⸩ ruby     
days = "abc
puts "Here are the days"
-:2: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting $end
puts "Here are the days"
          ^
```

It's treating the double-quote before the word "Here" as the closing quote of the string on the previous line, and then wondering why you're using a constant called Here (token beginning with upper case letter).

Answer (score 6):

The error message means that the ruby parser encountered a constant (i.e. an identifier starting with a capital letter) where it did not expect one (specifically the parser expected the file to end at that point).

Since the code you've shown does not even contain a constant, the problem is likely caused by another part of your code.