# syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input

Tags: android, calabash

I'm having some issues defining my own steps using Calabash-Android and Cucumber.

My step definition file contains

```
require 'calabash-android/calabash_steps'

Given /^I wait for obb download$/ do
    pending
end
```

And the error message I am getting is

```
Calabash-Android/features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input

Given /^I wait for obb download$/ ...
...                               ^ (SyntaxError)
```

I have tried using the `Given` and `When` prepositions and no matter what I put inside the `do` block, I get the same error. When I comment out `requires`, it will run, but crash when I get to that step. It also works when I comment out my step definition and remove my step.

I have also tried every combination of `/` `/^`, `/`, `$/`, and `""` and I still get the same error.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the exact 
1.) step definition you wrote. 
2.) The step you called in your feature file.
3.) Error log from the console.

Comment: check this one too..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317332/what-is-syntax-error-unexpected-tconstant-error-in-ruby

Comment: @ChathuraPalihakkara

1.) The first box is the exact definition

2.) `Given I wait on obb download`

3.) The second box is the exact error log


I already saw that link. The issue with that link was failing to close quotations, but I've already checked and changed mine to every possible combination. I even copy-pasted straight from the Github Wiki on it to no success.

Comment: I just check it with
`Given /^I wait for obb download$/ do
  puts "obb download"
end`

it works fine. may be your pending action have some syntax error.

Comment: I tried your code and I am getting the exact same thing. Here's a screenshot with irrelevant stuff cropped out: http://cl.ly/UrEd. Maybe that would help more.

Comment: Can you check your calabash-android console working ? (do UI queries get correct answers?). It seems step is correct. Did it work fine for other steps definitions you wrote?

Comment: That's my only step definition. Everything else I have in my features file are [canned steps](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/canned_steps.md). And I cannot check if those work because they time out while waiting on the obbs to download. I tried changing the wait_timeout globally and by using the canned step `Then I wait up to 3600 seconds...`(big download), but that still times out way too soon, so I am trying this and using `wait_for(:timeout => 3600) {...` in hopes that it will work.

Comment: Did you try UI queries...Try some and check weather system environment works fine.  https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/05-Query-Syntax

Open your app manually on the simulator and run a query from  console.